# What extrinsics when executed, would need an epoch or an era change to see effects?

Tags: extrinsic

For example, I executed a increaseValidatorCount (additional 1) extrinsic using `sudo` and I am still seeing blocks finalized with one validator. Does this imply I have to wait until next epoch  or era to see this change implemented? I ask this because I am not sure when would the change take effect (A change in session, or a re-election of validator sets). Are there some examples of other extrinsics that don't take effect until a similar epoch/era change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the sessions & staking generally work on epochs, you don't want to make a change mid-flight. So anything staking-related is (purposefully) delayed.

Answer (score 0):

One I can think of is adding a collator for the statemine parachain:

1. One would add the account to the session
2. run the `collatorSelection registerAsCandidate()` extrinsic. The collator bond would be deposited.
3. The collator account would be added to the session's validators on the next session change.

(I think for polkadot's babe one has to wait two sessions before seeing a change, as one does not want a last minute change to influence the [verifiable random number](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-randomness#vrf) that the next session is just about to use.)